# Director .app (Mac application) files won't copy to a PC

Tags: windows-xp, mac, osx-snow-leopard, adobe-flash

I have a few Mac applications that I would like to transfer to a Windows computer. One was created using Adobe Director 11.0 and the rest were created using Adobe Flash CS4.

The one created by Flash has no troubles whatsoever. The ones created using Director can't be copied to a Windows machine.

I am using Snow Leopard and I tried to copy to Windows XP from CD, which was burned on the Mac. Development took place on the Mac as well.

Comment: Do you get an error message or some other indication why it cannnot be copied?

Comment: Yes, it's something like it can't copy files inside the Frameworks folder inside the package. Specifically: ProjLib.framework -> ProjLib (which is an alias btw.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's *POSSIBLE* (but not very likely) that if you are using a very old program (it doesn't look like you are, but I figured I'd mention the possibility anyway) that your program is using resources. if you open the .app folder and poke around, if you see and .rsrc files you are using resources.

The problem with resources is that back in the olden days, mac files had two parts, or "forks" the data fork which is the normal, visible, part, and the resource fork which you couldn't normally see. No other system (That I know of) has a resource fork, so when you copy files with a resource fork to a PC, you just lose that part of the file, and everything breaks.

If you are just copying this to the PC as a waystation (andwhy else would you be doing this?) and you plan to copy it back to a mac, then, Kio's suggestion of zipping the .app folder is a good one, Mac's compress feature compresses the rsrc and data forks and the whole thing should be visible to the PC.

Comment: I have a feeling you are correct, upon further investigation, the package contains a file ProjLib.rsrc, which I suspect is the one that does not want be transferred and breaks the copying process.

The reason for the Windows transfer is because the client will be copying the application to his students' flashdrives, on a Windows machine and I only wanted Mac users to be able to use the application as well. He would obviously copy it for them onto their drives using his PC, so this is why it is a problem.

Comment: But I also looked at the Flash projector and it also contains .rsrc files, but I do not have problems copying this file.

I suspect it has something to do with the permissions on the individual .rsrc files in the Director projector (.app).

Answer (score 1):

Since Windows can't run the Mac application and will likely add a few completely unneeded files (thumbs.db, etc) to the directory (because all Mac .app files are folders that contain many files and folders), I would suggest compressing your Mac application into a .zip file first which will preserve the contents for when you deliver it to a suitable computer that can actually run the application.

To compress anything using the Finder's built in tools, right-click (or control-click) the item and select "Compress ".  In a moment, you'll have a fresh .zip file you can transfer to your Windows file server or wherever you care.